# ListView ItemClick open TabPage

Tags: c#, windows

[SCREEN SHOT](http://jafile.com/uploads/scoop/screenshot__41_.png)

**So the question is, is it possible to display the tabpagebuttons in the listview using  ToolStripMenuItem_Click or how can I use by clicking an listviewitem to open the tabpage I want?**

In my other app I created an scollbox with 30 radiobuttons and an tabcontrol with 30 tabs (tabs are hidden and can not be clicked)

I used this code to open the tabpages

```
    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl2.SelectedTab = tabPage4;
    }
```